# When to consider the noise safety coefficient as bad or good?

Tags: networking, home-networking, bandwidth, adsl, vdsl

I moved to new house and I have VDSL service exactly like the one I have before but I'm having issues with speed dropping, sometimes I get full speed which is 20 Mbps and sometimes I get 2 Mbps, so I looked into the connection details in the router and compare them to my old connection details and I found downstream noise safety coefficient is much higher than before.

```
DSL synchronization status:Up
Connection status:Showtime
Upstream line rate (kbit/s): 1119
Downstream line rate (kbit/s):22527
Maximum upstream rate (kbit/s):21517
Maximum downstream rate (kbit/s):144608
Upstream noise safety coefficient (dB):38.2
Downstream noise safety coefficient (dB):39.1
Upstream interleave depth:15
Downstream interleave depth:545
Line standard:VDSL
Upstream line attenuation (dB):0.3
Downstream line attenuation (dB):4.3
Upstream output power (dBm):-8.3
Downstream output power (dBm):10.7
Channel type:Interleaved
```

So when to consider the noise safety coefficient as bad one or good one ?

Comment: Check the cables or you Could use a spectral scan and check the less noisy channel and turn into it and sometimes the BGN protocol can be conflicting with some devices that doesn't support it so best is to chose bg or n depending on your needs and even check the frequency if it's 20/40 if your all devices are compatible with 40 you should simply change it to 40 cause sometimes it causes interference by switching from 20 to 40 or vice versa and you can always optimize your MTU but it's not really important or you might be using all your FUP limit per day that's why it's dropping down?

Comment: @elie first thanks, so everything is normal in my connection details ? because the downstream noise safety coefficient in my old connection was 11.9 dB and the internet was great. And about FUP limit , there is no limit per day and what I mean by dropping in speed is I tested it twice like in 1 min and I got 20Mb and the other test 2Mb and so on , it's not constant. and my question was when to tell if the noise safety coefficient is bad ?